# Can not find MavenDependencyResolver in my class path.

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, jboss-arquillian

I am using this [tutorial](http://blog.diabol.se/?p=322) in order to write integration tests for my project. I added such dependencies to my project:

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
                <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-bom</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-alpha-1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.11.Final</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
                        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
                        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-bom</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.archetypes</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee6-webapp-archetype</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

And I try this code in deployment method:

```
@Deployment
public static Archive createDeployment() {
    return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "fileviewer.war")
            .addAsLibraries(
                    DependencyResolvers.use(MavenDependencyResolver.class)
                            .artifact("commons-io:commons-io:2.1")
                            .artifact("org.json:json:20090211")
                            .resolveAsFiles());
}
```

But I can not find `DependencyResolvers` and `MavenDependencyResolver` classes in my classepath, this classes supose to be in `shrinkwrap-resolver-bom`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you mention dependencies in `<dependencyManagement>` tag, it simply means that these dependencies are just available to use. In order for you to use them, you should explicitly include it outside of the `<dependencyManagement>` tag (Just like how you have done for `boss-as-arquillian-container-managed` and `jboss-javaee6-webapp-archetype`).
So, in your case either remove the `<dependencyManagement>` tag or include `shrinkwrap-resolver-bom` outside of the `<dependencyManagement>` tag once again.

Also, using `<dependencyManagement>` tag makes more sense when you are dealing with a multi-module maven project (where you have 1 parent module and several child modules) and when you want to control the dependencies and its versions from within the parent pom.
In your case, if you are working with just 1 module, then I would suggest removing the `<dependencyManagement>` tag and include all your dependencies within just the `<dependencies>` tag. That should be sufficient.